# Cannot change entire Windows 10 system from Spanish to English

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

I bought an Asus laptop several years ago and for some reason the operating system is partly in Spanish. For example, when I go to the Start menu, the menu options are listed in Spanish (Documentos, Imagenes, etc.). In Configuracion, I've set the Region to the United States and the Language to English (though it shows up as Ingles), but still many settings are in Spanish.

Here's a photo showing some settings listed in Spanish and some in English.

[image: photo of settings in spanish and english]

How can I change everything on the computer from Spanish to English?

Comment: In *Settings > Time & language > Language* (Idioma), click on the language `lnglés` and then on *Options*. Is "Language pack" marked as installed? If any options can be added, add all of them.